# how can I get plane from mouse drag in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, intersection, raycasting

I have two points from mouse drag event, and I want to slice something with these points like ninja fruits. So I want a plane for intersection test, I now have two rays from two mouse points.

How can I get a plane with these two parallel rays?

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) // left mouse down
{
    _lastMousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
}

if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) // left mouse up
{
    Vector3 nowMousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    GetCutPlane(_lastMousePosition, nowMousePosition);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need three points in 3D to get a plane.
Assuming the third point is camera itself we get this code

```
new Plane(_lastMousePosition, nowMousePosition, Camera.main.transform.position);
```